# How do I convert all strings (like "Fault") and into a unique float?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras

I have a DataFrame that has `int`, `float`, and `object` (strings with characters) items in it. I want a unique float for every unique object like so-

```
Exhuast
Fault
Probation
Exhaust
Fault
Motor
```

to

```
1.
2.
3.
1.
2.
4.
```

Also, will it work on all of the columns or would I have to do column by column?

Last question, will it also convert all the `int`'s to `float`'s as well?

Comment: Have you looked at: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.factorize.html?highlight=factorize#pandas.Series.factorize ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by Jon, you could make use of [`Series.factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.factorize.html?highlight=factorize#pandas.Series.factorize).

```
(s.factorize()[0]+1).astype('float')
```

To perform this column-wise over an entire DataFrame, just use `apply`.

**Demo**

```
>>> s = pd.Series(['Exhaust', 'Fault', 'Probation', 5, int,
                   'Exhaust', int, 'Fault', 'Motor'])

>>> s
0          Exhaust
1            Fault
2        Probation
3                5
4    <class 'int'>
5          Exhaust
6    <class 'int'>
7            Fault
8            Motor
dtype: object

>>> (s.factorize()[0]+1).astype('float')
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  1.,  5.,  2.,  6.])
```

---

A NumPy solution may be to use the `return_inverse` keyword arg of `np.unique`,

```
(np.unique(s, return_inverse=True)[1]+1).astype('float')
```

however from some rough benchmarking the Pandas solution may be faster.

Comment: Thank you so much!